# Error stating Entity map does not exist on target when the solution contains no relationships

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I start in the DEV environment

- I created a blank solution.
- I added Business Unit entity to it
- I did not add any subcomponent, left "Include entity metadata" checked
- I then went to Components -> Entities -> Business Unit, expanded Fields, clicked Add Subcomponents
- I picked one Rollup custom field, left "Include entity metadata" checked

I exported the solution as Unmanaged

I opened the STAGING environment (same as DEV except for the customizations I'm trying to bring over from DEV)

I tried to import the solution. Import ***fails***.

This is the error (copy-pasted from the log file, reformatted for readability):

> Entity Mapping
>
> businessunit-opportunity
>
> Failure
>
> 0x80048010
>
> EntityMap businessunit -> opportunity - Import: FAILURE. This entity map does not exist on the target system.

What is the CRM trying (and failing) to do ? Everything related to Business Unit (custom and/or standard) already exists in the target environment, I literally only have this custom field to bring over (I can go and create it by hand of course, but I'd rather stick to solutions...)

Comment: Did this ever get resolved?

Comment: @Daryl Not really, it happened again occasionally when trying to do similar exports too. I suspect the solution isn't including something that should be there (i.e. a part of a relationship and such) but I still have to find a definite answer (and the docs don't seem to address this particular error...)

Answer (score 1):

Check the customization file for a mapping from between BusinessUnit and Opportunity, with no actual mappings define.  Delete the XML for that mapping and try to import again.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be caused by having a reference in your solution to a relationship (e.g. a subgrid using a custom relationship) that is not included in the solution.
CRM will not complain when exporting the solution, but will fail on import with the above error.

Resolve the issue by adding the relationship (and necessary lookup field in the case of 1:N/N:1-relationships) to the solution.